# sed throws 'bad flag in substitute command' but works fine in package.json

Tags: bash, sed

Below works inside package.json

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13198#issuecomment-302917321

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "sed -i '' 's\/#import <RCTAnimation\\/RCTValueAnimatedNode.h>\/#import \"RCTValueAnimatedNode.h\"\/' ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedNodesManager.h",
  ...rest scripts
}
```

But if I move the command to a `postinstall.sh` and try to execute it, it results in an error

postinstall.sh:

```
sed -i '' 's\/#import <RCTAnimation\\/RCTValueAnimatedNode.h>\/#import \"RCTValueAnimatedNode.h\"\/' ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedNodesManager.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original command is more complex than it needs to be, leading to unnecessary and confusing escaping.

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "sed -i '' 's|#import <RCTAnimation/RCTValueAnimatedNode.h>|#import \"RCTValueAnimatedNode.h\"|' ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedNodesManager.h",
  ...rest scripts
}
```

so the extracted `sed` command should simply be

```
sed -i '' 's|#import <RCTAnimation/RCTValueAnimatedNode.h>|#import "RCTValueAnimatedNode.h"|' \
  ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedNodesManager.h
```

The only difference is that you don't need to escape the `"` in the replacement text.

As an aside, using `sed -i` usually means you can just use `ed`, the file editor which the stream editor `sed` is based on.

```
printf '%s\n' \
  's|#import <RCTAnimation/RCTValueAnimatedNode.h>|#import "RCTValueAnimatedNode.h"|' \
  'wq' |
  ed ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedNodesManager.h
```